# iOS app Blocker possibilities

Tags: ios

I know that iOS apps run in a sandbox and have no means of accessing other apps/system settings, but there seem to be products claiming to be able to "block distracting apps" etc on an iPhone, for example familyTime which acts as a parental control tool.
So my question is: is there a possible workaround for an application to be able to block apps on iOS? Something else besides a safari content blocker? Freedom app seems to create a custom vpn session which restricts access to some sites, is this the max we can do to restrict using distracting apps on an iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to `Parental Control` kind of application, a possible solution will be `Device Enrollment Program`.

> The Device Enrollment Program (DEP) is part of the Apple Deployment
>   Programs (ADP), which help businesses and educational institutions
>   easily deploy and configure iOS and OS X devices. DEP provides a fast,
>   streamlined way to deploy institutionally owned iPad and iPhone
>   devices and Mac computers that are purchased directly from Apple or
>   participating Apple Authorized Resellers or carriers.

Hope it will help.
It will give you the controls like below mentioned and I guess this is one we are looking for.

- Mandatory and lockable MDM enrollment, it ensures that device configured based on your organization’s requirements, and guarantees that all
  users receive those configurations on their devices.

For more, you can also visit [This Apple Documentation](http://images.apple.com/education/docs/DEP_Guide.pdf).

But when it comes to the use case like block the application using iOS application, so there is not public API provided by `Apple`.