# Block app install from AppStore and app delete using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, app-store

I am aware that we can [**block safari content**](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift/create-a-safari-content-blocker/) using swift code. I am interested in finding out if we can restrict install of certain apps from AppStore using similar approach ?
Also, is it possible if we can restrict a user from deleting the app from device (not from phone settings but from code) ? Even if Apple does not allow that to publish such app, I am looking for a solution as a part of research.

Comment: Please share the reason for down vote. I am looking for swift code which does that. I think question falls in the guidelines.

Comment: I don't think there will be any `public API` provided by `Apple` for restricting the user from deleting the app from the device, `Jailbroken` device might be possible but no clue. And for restricting for certain apps to download from `App Store` maybe this link will help.[https://stackoverflow.com/a/46724720/1603380].

Comment: @Buntylm : Thanks. Will be a sure help in this. I wasn't aware of this program.

Comment: sounds good, I would like to add that there are already lots of related question on SO but not same, that may because of the downvote but I also want to see the reason for download and close vote here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you mentioned.

> First, can restrict install of certain apps from AppStore

Using `Swift` code I feel there are no `Public API` provided by `Apple` for the developer till now but there is a similar way that is called `Device Enrollment Program`.

> The Device Enrollment Program (DEP) is part of the Apple Deployment
>   Programs (ADP), which help businesses and educational institutions
>   easily deploy and configure iOS and OS X devices. DEP provides a fast,
>   streamlined way to deploy institutionally owned iPad and iPhone
>   devices and Mac computers that are purchased directly from Apple or
>   participating Apple Authorized Resellers or carriers.

For more visit this [developer guide](http://images.apple.com/education/docs/DEP_Guide.pdf).

> Second: restrict a user from deleting the app from device

Same response for that, till now no `Developer API`, but lets say if we see this as a part of research and we develop some `POC` still, it does not make sense for me at all (It's my device and I install the app for making my life easy and better if I don't want to use it anymore, I need an option to delete it) and I don't think so this will be possible in future as well because the USP for iOS device is user experience and we can't make this like that.

I also want to hear something from others and if possible give the use case why you are looking a solution like that.
I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.